# Python: keep 'cls' annotation for custom classmethod implementation

Tags: python, properties, pycharm, annotations

So what i created at first was my own implementation of class-property. It behaves like normal property, but actually applied to a class:

```
class classproperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return classmethod(self.fget).__get__(None, owner)()

class A:
    @classproperty
    def f(cls):
        return 1
```

It works just fine, but PyCharm highlights `cls` and says that "Usually first parameter of a method is named 'self' ".

[image]

The question is: is there any way to tell PyCharm/interpreter, that `@classproperty` is actually a sort of `classmethod` and that i want to preserve `cls` as name for first parameter?

I've tried setting `metaclass=classmethod`, but that caused `TypeError: metaclass conflict`. Making `classproprty` to extend both inherit both `property` and `classmethod` also gave me `TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict` which is kind of expected.

So can i trick it into thinking that my decorator is a kind of `classmethod`?